# how to return only query time and not the data

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the SQuirreL application from sourceforge to query and extract info from my data sources. Some of the data though are huge and I don't really need to see it, I am only interested in how long it took to run the whole query.

So I am wondering if there is any command in SQL that I can add to a SELECT statement to run the query but not bring back any data just the time that it took to retrieve the data?

Thanks

Comment: Hm, not entirely AFAIK. One could run `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE somename AS SELECT ...` AFAIK, but that CREATE of course has its own overhead.

Comment: You probably don't really care how long the query runs on the database.  I would think it's a lot more important to see how long it takes to return all the rows.

Comment: Yeah Andrew, you are correct. I am only interested in knowing how long it would take to return all rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL Query profiler](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) to do something similar:

```
mysql> set profiling=1;
select * from table;
mysql> show profiles;
```

This should show you something like:

```
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                                         |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|        0 | 0.00007300 | set profiling=1                               |
|        1 | 0.00044700 | select * from table;                          |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Alternately you could do something hacky with `microtime()`, something like:

```
// Grab the start time
$start = microtime(true);

// Execute your query
mysql_query('select * from table');

// Do something with the execution time
echo microtime(true) - $start .' seconds';
```

But obviously this is **far** from ideal (and you shouldn't be using `mysql_*`)!

Comment: Hi Tom, the set and show profile doesn't seem to work via SQuirreL and I need to incorporate the solution into SQuirreL... any other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked with SQuirreL so I can really help with that specifically.